# Multi Label Classification: Error in predicting accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, multilabel-classification

I am new to multilabel classification and I am using Binary Relevance as the classifier. The ML model works fine but when I try to get the accuracy metrics: hamming loss, accuracy scores I get this error as:

```
in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     79     if len(y_type) > 1:
     80     raise ValueError("Classification metrics can't handle a 
            mix of {0} "
    ---> 81  "and {1} targets".format(type_true, 
   type_pred))
     82 
     83     # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no 
          more needed

            ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of 
             binary and multilabel-indicator targets
```

I did raise a question in also
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/58912/binaryrelevence-classifier-giving-errors-during-predicting-accuracy-scores

Can someone please tell why this error pops up and ways of resolving this issue.